# Restful Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing a simple look up that checks to see if a username already exists in the database.  So far things have been fairly straight forward. However I do have an issue with how I am doing my routing.

Currently in my routes.rb I have the following:

```
namespace :broker do
    namespace :userdesk do
        resources :dashboards do
        end
        resources :accounts do      
            get :validateUsername
        end
    end
 end
```

When I use rake routes, I get the following route for validateUsername:
`broker_userdesk_account_validateUsername GET    /broker/userdesk/accounts/:account_id/validateUsername(.:format) {:action=>"validateUsername", :controller=>"broker/userdesk/accoun
ts"}`

For this action, I am passing the username and not the account_id. Is there a way to modify the route so that it uses something like this:
`/broker/userdesk/accounts/:username/validateUsername(.:format)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this doesn't seem particularly 'Railsy' or RESTful but you could define a specific route using `match`

```
match '/broker/userdesk/accounts/:username/validateUsername' => 'broker/userdesk/accounts#validateUsername'
```

**UPDATED**

I recommend the rails guide on routing:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

*I have ignored your namespaces in my examples.*

If you are nesting within the accounts resource, you would expect to scope by an account, not a username.

It would be more RESTful to try something like `/users/:id/validate`.

In fact, if all you are doing is checking if the user exists, you could hit the show action of users and handle 404s:

```
resources :users # would give you /users/:id where you would either return a user or a not found (400)
```

Comment: Can you explain how it does not seem "Railsy"? I would prefer to follow best practices rather that use a hack method.

Comment: I am not checking to see if a specific user or user id exists. I am validating whether or not a username exists. So using the show action is not really an option. This check is done from the create user form. Once a user focuses out of the username field this check is run.

Comment: params[:id] is just a convention for the name of the variable. It does not have to be numeric. Are you going to have places where you look up users using different fields (primary key and username)? In anycase you could use /users/:id/validate_username and send a username as the id param.